# Cakephp3 Auth Password not encrypted

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp3 and auth components for login/logout. 
My [users] table, users.[password] column is not encrypted just normal characters.
Is therere a way not to use or override auth passwordHasher?

Comment: If your data isn't hashed, then you already are _not_ using password hashing (which is generally a very bad idea)!?

Comment: What does "not encrypted" mean? What is stored instead? What have you tried to enable such encryption?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named `User.php` with the below content in `/src/Model/Entity` folder. This will automatically encrypt your password while saving.

```
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher; 
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class User extends Entity
{


    protected function _setPassword($value)
    {
        if (strlen($value)) {
            $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();

            return $hasher->hash($value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also hash password in the controller like below. 
Use password Hash library in controller.

```
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
```

Now you can use the following code to hash you password string like this.

```
$password = "Your Password";
$hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
$hasher->hash($password);
```

Comment: @NicoHaase you can put this just before saving the data. Means in the controller in which you have written the code for save data.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
```

On registration use this

```
$user = $this->Users->newEntity();
$hasher = new new DefaultPasswordHasher();
$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
$user->password=$hasher->hash($user->password); //follow this
if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
}
```